# Postman 6.7.3 - how to use logged-on user for Authorization/NTLM Authentication?

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman 6.7.3. Instead of typing in the Username and Password values for the Authorization (tab) NTLM Authentication (type), alternatively, I'd like Postman to retrieve the needed information from the logged-on user. Is that possible today? I'm running a "corporate"-configured version of Windows 10 that resides on an (AD) domain (that we call "US").

FWIW, my "web api" calls work just fine when I do type-in the credentials for myself in the Postman Authorization screen. (just looking to do "less typing"...and perhaps avoid the security risk of exposing my domain password)